# finding the average number of comparisons

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like to write an algorithm to find min and max of 100000 arrays 100000 with the size of 1000, containing random numbers from 1 to 1000. This algorithm suppose to return the average number of comparisons.

Suppose I use a naive solution with the complexity of O(n) , what does the average number of comparisons suppose to be? 1999 or 2000 (to min and max)?

I also would like to ask how to creat a random array in cpp.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare every element twice (once to the current min, once to the current max).

That's not "naive", it's the optimal way to find min and max of unsorted numbers.

Comment: how do you prove it?

Comment: optimal is not to check for maximum if the element matched for minimum - or vice versa. The improvement is negligible though on average.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between naive and simple / optimal ,it's always good to look for other solutions , but not always you are going to find a better or more optimal one .

as for your question you have to compare them twice once as a min and once as a max

Answer (score 0):

Well, I disagree with the Sid's answer as checking each element with max and min is optimal.

Firstly, you can take first two elements and compare them together and set one as min and another as maximum.

Then you can easily in loop take 2 elements at once, compare them together and check lower one with the minimum and bigger one with the maximum.

Therefore on 2 elements you have only 3 comparisons.

It is better than checking each number with minimum and maximum, because you have 4 comparisons on 2 elements.